# How to avoid import evaluation until if wil return true

Tags: import, variable

My goal is to import a data from url that depends of 1 parameter, this initialy value is null or undifined en yo have to selec some popup and then the variable has value, what is the method to do that?

```
years = Import["http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/year",
    "XML"];
    y = Cases[years, XMLElement["menuItem", _, _], Infinity] /. 
    XMLElement[_, _, {val_}] ->  val /. 
   XMLElement["menuItem", _, list_] -> list;
    Do[y[[i]] = DeleteDuplicates[y[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[y], 1}];
    years = y[[All, 1]];
Manipulate[ 
    makes = 
  Import[StringJoin[
    "http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/make?year=", 
    URLEncode[ToString@year]], "XML"];
    m = Cases[makes, XMLElement["menuItem", _, _], Infinity] /. 
    XMLElement[_, _, {val_}] ->  val /. 
   XMLElement["menuItem", _, list_] -> list;
    Do[m[[i]] = DeleteDuplicates[m[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[m], 1}];
    makes = m[[All, 1]];

    models = 
  Import[StringJoin[
    "http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/model?year=", 
    URLEncode[ToString@year], "&make=", URLEncode[ToString@make]], 
   "XML"];
    mo = Cases[models, XMLElement["menuItem", _, _], Infinity] /. 
    XMLElement[_, _, {val_}] ->  val /. 
   XMLElement["menuItem", _, list_] -> list;
    Do[mo[[i]] = DeleteDuplicates[mo[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[mo], 1}];
    models = mo[[All, 1]];

    options = 
  Import[StringJoin[
    "http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/options?year=", 
    URLEncode[ToString@year], "&make=", URLEncode[ToString@make], 
    "&model=", URLEncode[ToString@model]], "XML"];
 o = Cases[options, XMLElement["menuItem", _, _], Infinity] /. 
    XMLElement[_, _, {val_}] ->  val /. 
   XMLElement["menuItem", _, list_] -> list;
    Do[o[[i]] = DeleteDuplicates[o[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[o], 1}];
    options = o[[All, 1]];
    ids = o[[All, 2]];

    p = Position[options, option];
    c  = Length[p];
    car = Import[
   StringJoin["http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/", 
    ids[[p[[1, 1]]]]], "XML"];

    Row[{"Choosen car: ", option, car}],
    {year, years},
    Control@{make, Dynamic@makes, PopupMenu},
    Control@{model, Dynamic@models, PopupMenu},
    Control@{option, Dynamic@options, PopupMenu},
    Control@{car, Dynamic, None},
    TrackedSymbols :> {make, year, model, option, car},
 ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

Okay the problem is in car variable, I tried enclosing on if but it dont work and allways return the false statement, so how can I get the position of picked car to use it on ids list to import the specific car avoiding the import unitl ids have values

Comment: I think yours is a pretty thorny issue. I suggest a simplification for your code to extract e.g. the `years` variable without intermediate variables and looping: `Cases[Import["http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/year", 
  "XML"], XMLElement["value", {}, {yr_}] -> yr, Infinity]`. You can use something like this for all your data extraction. For your main problem, a start might be assigning default initial values to the `Manipulate` variables, but that doesn't solve all problems. I'll give this some more thought.

Comment: My real problem is that mahtematica try to import from url before the user picked all values  ` StringJoin["http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/", 
    ids[[p[[1, 1]]]]], "XML"];` so this ids[[p[[1,1]]]] cause an error, and i want to avoid this part of the code until p has some data, I tried with if and which but it not work